# Apache Beam version upgrade fails the ETL Pipeline

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am currently using Apache Beam version 2.39.0 and it is showing me errors on dataflow

> This version of the SDK is deprecated and will eventually no longer be
> supported. Learn more

I am trying to upgarde from 2.39.0 to 2.48.0 and when I run mvn compile clean with dataflow args then it fails with below error

```
mvn clean compile exec:java  -Pdataflow-runner -Dexec.mainClass=com.Test "-Dexec.args=--runner=DataflowRunner --region=europe-west9 --serviceAccount=test@test.iam.gserviceaccount.com --maxNumWorkers=2 --workerMachineType=e2-standard-8 --gcpTempLocation=gs://test/test-template/ --stagingLocation=gs://test/test/template/staging --templateLocation=gs://test/test-template/templates/cron-template --sourceProject=test
```

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: io.grpc.LoadBalancerProvider: io.grpc.xds.WeightedRoundRobinLoadBalancerProvider Unable to get public no-arg constructor
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:586)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:679)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1240)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1273)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1309)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1393)
    at io.grpc.ServiceProviders.loadAll(ServiceProviders.java:67)
    at io.grpc.LoadBalancerRegistry.getDefaultRegistry(LoadBalancerRegistry.java:102)
    at io.grpc.internal.AutoConfiguredLoadBalancerFactory.<init>(AutoConfiguredLoadBalancerFactory.java:53)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.<init>(ManagedChannelImpl.java:635)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(ManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:630)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:297)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:404)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.access$1900(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:85)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider$1.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:246)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.<init>(ChannelPool.java:149)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:96)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:256)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:234)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:241)
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.stub.GrpcKeyManagementServiceStub.create(GrpcKeyManagementServiceStub.java:430)
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.stub.KeyManagementServiceStubSettings.createStub(KeyManagementServiceStubSettings.java:591)
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient.<init>(KeyManagementServiceClient.java:156)
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient.create(KeyManagementServiceClient.java:137)
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient.create(KeyManagementServiceClient.java:128)
    at com.yapily.etl.rawdata.kms.KMSEncryptedNestedValueProvider.decryptWithKMS(KMSEncryptedNestedValueProvider.java:91)
    at com.yapily.etl.rawdata.kms.KMSEncryptedNestedValueProvider$KmsTranslatorInput.apply(KMSEncryptedNestedValueProvider.java:55)
    at com.yapily.etl.rawdata.kms.KMSEncryptedNestedValueProvider$KmsTranslatorInput.apply(KMSEncryptedNestedValueProvider.java:29)
    at com.yapily.etl.rawdata.kms.DualInputNestedValueProvider.get(DualInputNestedValueProvider.java:67)
    at com.yapily.etl.rawdata.yapilyconnect.billingextraction.BillingDataExtraction.main(BillingDataExtraction.java:41)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class io.grpc.xds.WeightedRoundRobinLoadBalancer cannot inherit from final class io.grpc.util.RoundRobinLoadBalancer
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:524)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:427)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:420)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3373)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3578)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2271)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:666)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:663)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:674)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

### EDIT 1

By looking at the error I realised class is `RoundRobinLoadBalancer`  is final and `WeightedRoundRobinLoadBalancerProvider` is trying to extend it and thus failure happens.
I looked at the version that I have for `grpc-core` which is 1.44.x and it has `RoundRobinLoadBalancer` class. I excluded `grpc-core` from `beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform` and added `grpc-core` explictly with `1.55.1` as a dependency which has `RoundRobinLoadBalancer` as public. I got rid of main error but started seeing another error

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. io/grpc/InternalGlobalInterceptors
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:339)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:370)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/grpc/InternalGlobalInterceptors
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImplBuilder.getEffectiveInterceptors(ManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:643)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(ManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:631)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:297)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:404)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.access$1900(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:85)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider$1.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:246)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.<init>(ChannelPool.java:149)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:96)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:256)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:234)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:241)
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.stub.GrpcKeyManagementServiceStub.create(GrpcKeyManagementServiceStub.java:430)
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.stub.KeyManagementServiceStubSettings.createStub(KeyManagementServiceStubSettings.java:591)
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient.<init>(KeyManagementServiceClient.java:156)
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient.create(KeyManagementServiceClient.java:137)
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient.create(KeyManagementServiceClient.java:128)
    at com.yapily.etl.rawdata.kms.KMSEncryptedNestedValueProvider.decryptWithKMS(KMSEncryptedNestedValueProvider.java:91)
    at com.yapily.etl.rawdata.kms.KMSEncryptedNestedValueProvider$KmsTranslatorInput.apply(KMSEncryptedNestedValueProvider.java:55)
    at com.yapily.etl.rawdata.kms.KMSEncryptedNestedValueProvider$KmsTranslatorInput.apply(KMSEncryptedNestedValueProvider.java:29)
    at com.yapily.etl.rawdata.kms.DualInputNestedValueProvider.get(DualInputNestedValueProvider.java:67)
    at com.yapily.etl.rawdata.yapilyconnect.vrpdataextraction.VRPDataExtraction.main(VRPDataExtraction.java:40)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.grpc.InternalGlobalInterceptors
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

How should I fix this error ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are having some dependency conflicts here and mismatching versions of gRPC.

How are you bringing matching versions of dependencies?

The easiest way that I am aware is using the BOM provided by Beam: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#java-dependency-errors

Comment: It is still giving me same error after using BOM.

Comment: Did you drop any <version> of things that are defined by the BOM? Such as gax, grpc, anything google-cloud-*, etc